# Get button name or Id in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, button

Looking to identify which button was pressed through name or id as there are three buttons in my LWC that each trigger the same function.

I've used a standard html button so i could style it in a specific way (instead of lightning-button).

Button:

```
<button class="form-help-button" aria-describedby="help" id="BussNameButton" onclick={revealHelp}>
```

Some of the documentation showed the standard event being used with standard html elements (ie. event.target.name etc.). So that is what I tried by I have not had success:

```
revealHelp(event) {
   let id = event.target.id;

   console.log(id)
}
```

It is firing but id is undefined each time. Can i retrieve the id or name of a standard html button in lwc?

In this [Stack Exchange thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button), most solutions involve passing an attribute in the element which is not allowed in LWC

Answer (score -2, accepted):

event.currentTarget.id or event.currentTarget.name is the correct syntax, i was just off on that part. Also use name not Id as it was coming across with appended numbers (many others mention this as well)

Answer (score 13):

`id` shouldn't be used, because it is used by the framework for rendering purposes. Instead, just use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) to specify the name:

```
<button data-name="myButtonName" ... />
```

...

```
onClickHandler(event) {
    var buttonName = event.target.dataset.name;
    ...
```

...

Edit: I also created a quick [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/pj9_R08X/1/edit) that demonstrates this.

Comment: Wasnt planning on using Id, was just looking for syntax. I see its working in the fiddle but having issues in my component with data-attribute, seems to be causing an error. None the less, the currentTarget syntax does work. Thanks